# How to share my Rail's log file realtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, logging

I have Ubuntu machine thats running a Rails app. I want to share the log file with another developer so they can watch what is happening with the app in real time using a command such as this:

```
tail -f ~/railsapp/log/staging.log
```

What is the best way to do this without exposing all of my passwords, API keys, etc that are embedded in my Rails app?

I could create a group & user using the command:

```
groupadd logviewer
adduser lv1 --ingroup logviewer
```

Then remove permissions for others

```
chmod -R o-rwx ~/railsapp
```

Then re-add read permission for others

```
chmod -R o+rx ~/railsapp/log
```

Are there consequences to this approach? Is there a better way?

Added 3/5/2014 - Looks like this is also a good idea:

```
chmod -R o+rx ~/railsapp/public
```

Added 4/14/2014 - You're also to need to allow the path to the log directory...so:

```
chmod o+rx ~/railsapp
chmod o+rx ~/railsapp/log
```

Comment: Is this a temporary setup or are you looking to put something long term?

Comment: A long term setup is preferred. Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to sort this out?

Answer (score 1):

You may just grant the logviewers with the read and traversing access(r+x) to the directory other than the rails dirs where they would have no permission to read, but only the traversing permission through the path to the log file, and make a soft link to the log file.

`ln -s /railsapp/log/staging.log /to/somewhere/staging.log`

logviewers should have access to log files and the path /to/somewhere. The idea is to allow them read log only and can't read all the other files under railsapp.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to setup fileshare, and also have something that is more long term, I would recommend something that is a light http wrapper over log files.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078352/web-implementation-of-tail-f-filename) for more options, but my recommendation goes like this:

Use [`tailon`](http://tailon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and set it up to watch your rails logs:

```
tailon -f ~/railsapp/log/staging.log
```

This would then stream `staging.log` to localhost:8080

You could also have `tailon` stream to [nginx](http://tailon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#usage-with-nginx) and setup user access.

You may also want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7698484/326543), to see similar thing working with Sinatra and ruby :) - in case you do not want to use python based tools.

Comment: I would also like to mention [wtee](http://wtee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is a sister project of tailon. If you're only interested in following a single file, wtee could be the simpler solution (disclaimer: I'm the author of both projects).

Answer (score 0):

Create a unix user, create group, add the user to the group, add permission on reading the file (740), after all revoke rights and delete the group and the user.

Comment: Thanks...but I don't understand what you mean by "after all revoke rights".

Comment: just delete the user :) thats enough